# Add a background behind loader to hide loading screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

How can one add a bgcolor behind the loader before a page is created just to hide the white screen before the page is loaded.

this is my code.

```
setTimeout(function(){

     $.mobile.loading('show', {
    text: 'Chargement en cours...',
    textVisible: true,
    theme: 'a',
    html: "<span class='ui-bar ui-overlay-c ui-corner-all' ><img width='50px' height='50px' src='http://www.shougun.it/images/loading.gif' /><br><h2>Chargement en cours...</h2></span>"
});
    },5);
```

Can we set a background behind the span tag. Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="position: fixed;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);text-align: center"><span class='ui-bar ui-overlay-c ui-corner-all' style="text-align:center;display:inline-block"><img width='50px' height='50px' src='http://www.shougun.it/images/loading.gif' style="display:inline"/><br><h2>Chargement en cours...</h2></span></div>
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/qtfc83m2/

In your case this would be:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $.mobile.loading('show', {
        text: 'Chargement en cours...',
        textVisible: true,
        theme: 'a',
        html: '<div style="position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);text-align: center"><span class="ui-bar ui-overlay-c ui-corner-all" style="text-align:center;display:inline-block"><img width="50px" height="50px" src="http://www.shougun.it/images/loading.gif" style="display:inline"/><br><h2>Chargement en cours...</h2></span></div>'
    });
}, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can set a background behind the `ui-overlay-c` and use `div` as a wrapper.

Try this:

```
.ui-overlay-c {
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/urLsj7eu/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you want to do. this may be of help

http://jsfiddle.net/qtfc83m2/1/

```
setTimeout(function(){
$(".ui-bar").css("display","block");

    },2000);
```

Above code will show loading after 2 secdonds and if you want to reverse then change css and jquery to

```
setTimeout(function(){
$(".ui-bar").css("display","block");

    },5);

$(document).load(function() {
$(".ui-bar").css("display","none");
});
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-bar{
    display:block;
position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,.5);
    text-align:center;

}
```